# How to edit the cell type in a DataGrid Control wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my application I have a `Server` class which has public properties `Name` and `Connected`.

`Connected` is a bool which is updated by the each instance of the `Server` class.

Right now I have `DataGrid` which is autogenerating columns from a list of servers called servers.

Is there a way to change the dataGrid so that it shows "Connected" when `Connected` is true and "Disconnected" when `Connected` is false?

Comment: Data Grid Control, Edited my post to reflect this. Apologies on the confusion.

Comment: is `autogenerating columns` absolutely required? it is probably simpler to define 2 columns in xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `AutoGenerateColumns` is used, it is possible to handle `AutoGeneratingColumn` event in code behind and modify newly created `Connected` DataGridCheckBoxColumn. What I'm going to do, is to create a Trigger which will change status text depending of ChechBox checked state:

```
private void DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Connected")
    {
        var c = e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn;
        if (c == null)
            return;
        c.IsReadOnly = true;
        c.ElementStyle =
            new Style
            {
                TargetType = typeof (CheckBox),
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = ContentProperty, Value = "Disconnected" },
                    // prevent checking CheckBoxes 
                    new Setter { Property = IsHitTestVisibleProperty, Value = false },
                },
                Triggers =
                {
                    new Trigger
                    {                                
                        Property = CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, 
                        Value = true,
                        Setters =
                        {
                            new Setter { Property = ContentProperty, Value = "Connected" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    }
}
```

[image: result]

---

another idea: make a special property in a viewModel for connection status description.

```
public class Server
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Connected { get; set; }

    public string ConnectionStatus
    {
        get { return Connected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected"; }
    }
}
```

and then disable column generation for `Connected` property

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumnHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Connected")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!